# Solve simple ode $y'=y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\dfrac {dy}{dx}=y$$
$$\implies \dfrac {dy}{y}=dx$$
$$\ln y =x+C_1$$
$$y =C_2e^x$$
I am wondering whether it should be $\ln|y|=x+C_{1}$? or it does not matter because $C_2$ can be negative or positive?

Comment: Your solution is correct. $C_2$ can be positive or negative. With integrating factor method you have $y'-y=0 \implies (ye^{-x})'=0 \implies y=ce^x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid confusion, you can always use the trick to set boundaries when you integrate, in your case
$$
\int_{y=y(x_0)}^{y(x)}\frac{dy}{y}=\int_{x_0}^xds
$$
then you have
$$
[\ln y]_{y=y(x_0)}^{y(x)}=\ln\frac{y(x)}{y(x_0)}=x-x_0
$$
to give you
$$
y(x)=y(x_0)e^{x-x_0}=y(x_0)e^{-x_0}e^x.
$$
So now you have $C_2=y(x_0)e^{-x_0}$ and the sign of $C_2$ depends on the sign of the initial condition $y(x_0)$.

And if you are not given an intial condition, usually it is OK to assume one.

By my experience it is mostly better to integrate with boundaries as in this example. Then I can easier understand sensitivity and stability, I guess you will get there one day too. The idea is to see how initial condition influences the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If we asume one in the general condition, will that change our solution in the end?

Comment: What if y=y(x(0)) is a negative number, it seems that we do need absolute value sign.

Comment: For example $y(x)=-e^{x}$ then $y(0)=-1$. You also have in this example $y'(x)=y(x)$.

It could happen the problem you solve have multiple conditions, you will find the correct solution from those conditions, for example from initial values, boundary conditions etc.

Comment: @000000000 if $y(x_0)<0$ there is no issue, you just get $y(x)<0$ and $y(x)/y(x_0)>0$. The solution given in the answer is fully general and covers all cases. Absolute values don't come into it. With your method, yes you do need an absolute value, and then you can remove it after. But I think the answer makes a good point of when in doubt, use limits. An integral without a domain of integration can be a source of confusion (geometrically, it doesn't make much sense).